# VERCEL: Error: Unable to find any supported Python versions

Tags: python, django, flask, deployment, vercel

I'm trying to deploy some web apps with Python/Flask Vercel Templates and it's giving me an error in building:

`Error: Unable to find any supported Python versions.`

This has never happened before using vercel’s own templates.

build error:

[image: build error]

node version:

[image: node version]

I have seen previous reports that say about incompatibility with node 20.x, but the project is already configured with node 18.x

https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/6287

I tried redeploying for 2 days in a row and out of curiosity, testing the python-hello-world template as well, which generated the same deploy error.

I have seen previous reports that say about incompatibility with node 20.x, but the project is already configured with node 18.x

Answer (score 2):

- In the `vercel.json` file, you can specify the Python version like this:

  ```
  {
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "vercel_app/wsgi.py",
      "use": "@vercel/python",
      "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb", "runtime": "python3.8" }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "vercel_app/wsgi.py"
    }
  ]
  ```

}

Answer (score 0):

Editing "node" to 18.x package.json

```json
{
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.x"
  }
}
```

editing the node version even if it is already pre-configured as 18.x seems to solve the problem, the strange thing is that I tried it and the first attempt it didn't work, while trying again today the app completed the build.