# Deploy my Django rest framework app to Vercel

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, vercel

I'm trying to deploy my Django Rest framework app using vercel.
While building, I got an error "Error: Unable to find any supported Python versions."

My vercel.json is below.

```
{
"version": 2,
"regions": ["hnd1"],
"builds": [
{
    "src": "myproject/wsgi.py",
    "use": "@vercel/python",
    "config": {
    "maxLambdaSize": "15mb"
    }
},
{
    "src": "build_files.sh",
    "use": "@vercel/static-build",
    "config": { "distDir": "static" }
}
],
"routes": [
{
    "src": "/static/(.*)",
    "dest": "/static/$1"
},
{
    "src": "/(.*)",
    "dest": "myproject/wsgi.py"
}
]
}
```

I confirmed that I could successfully download django and other things. (it means build_files.sh is executed correctly.)
I think I might have problems with static files.
I added static root and url to settins.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

and added urlpatterns to urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Why is this error occurred?
I appreciate your opinion and advice!

Comment: What is your node version ? It seems it's a recent issue https://github.com/vercel/vercel/discussions/11128

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78233938/vercel-error-unable-to-find-any-supported-python-versions

Comment: I changed the node version to 18.x, and it works fine!
Thank you for your help.